# print 'Bone ', self.name Error in Blender 2.64

Tags: python, blender

I know nothing about blender scripting, but when I was trying to import a .Py script, it came up with this line and said that there was a syntax error.

```
print 'Bone       ', self.name
```

I've done some other programing languages in the past (Like VB And SB) But I was hoping one of you would enlighten me on what was going on.

the full code is [Here](http://www.sean.alyrica.net/supcom-importer.py)

Comment: Im going to guess you are executing Python 2.7 code with a Python 3 interpretter. In Python 3 print is a function and needs to be called accordingly. `print("Bone     ", self.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Blender includes Python 3.3. In Python 3.3, `print` is a function, not a statement. Change it to:

```
print('Bone       ', self.name)
```

There are very very likely many other such changes you'll need to make to the code, which was clearly written to run under Python 2.x.

Comment: Is there a way I could get the Python version it was meant for?

Comment: It would appear to be a pre-2.5 version as it is using the Blender module which was replaced by the bpy module.